# Split column by multiple delimiters, keeping delimiters

Tags: r, regex, data.table, strsplit

How can I split a character column into 3 columns using %, -, and + as the possible delimiters, keeping the delimiters in the new columns?

Example Data:

```
data <- data.table(x=c("92.1%+100-200","90.4%-1000+200", "92.8%-200+100", "99.2%-500-200","90.1%+500-200"))
```

Example desired data:

```
data.desired <- data.table(x1=c("92.1%", "90.4%", "92.8%","99.2%","90.1%")
                           , x2=c("+100","-1000","-200","-500","+500")
                           , x3=c("-200","+200","+100","-200","-200"))
```

Happy to award the points for a good answer and some help on this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `data.table` the equivalent is `tstrsplit`:

```
data[, c("x1","x2","x3") := tstrsplit(x, "(?<=.)(?=[+-])", perl=TRUE) ]
data
#                x    x1    x2   x3
#1:  92.1%+100-200 92.1%  +100 -200
#2: 90.4%-1000+200 90.4% -1000 +200
#3:  92.8%-200+100 92.8%  -200 +100
#4:  99.2%-500-200 99.2%  -500 -200
#5:  90.1%+500-200 90.1%  +500 -200
```

Answer (score 6):

We may use `separate` from `tidyr` for splitting and a positive lookahead as to keep the delimiters:

```
data %>% separate(x, c("x1", "x2", "x3"), sep = "(?=\\+|-)")
#       x1    x2   x3
# 1: 92.1%  +100 -200
# 2: 90.4% -1000 +200
# 3: 92.8%  -200 +100
# 4: 99.2%  -500 -200
# 5: 90.1%  +500 -200
```

---

That is, note that splitting simply by `\\+|-` we would get

```
data %>% separate(x, c("x1", "x2", "x3"), sep = "\\+|-")
#       x1   x2  x3
# 1: 92.1%  100 200
# 2: 90.4% 1000 200
# 3: 92.8%  200 100
# 4: 99.2%  500 200
# 5: 90.1%  500 200
```

Using `(?=\\+|-)` split at "nothing" in case right after that we have `+` or `-` (which are not matched).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
cbind(data, read.csv(text = gsub("(?=[+-])", ",", data$x, perl = TRUE), 
    header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')))
#                x    x1    x2   x3
#1:  92.1%+100-200 92.1%   100 -200
#2: 90.4%-1000+200 90.4% -1000  200
#3:  92.8%-200+100 92.8%  -200  100
#4:  99.2%-500-200 99.2%  -500 -200
#5:  90.1%+500-200 90.1%   500 -200
```